# Shortcut key for increasing/decreasing current split panes width/height?

Tags: visual-studio-code

Is there a quick keyboard shortcut to control the width of the current split pane, at least increasing and decreasing it?

for vim users it would be:

```
:vertical resize 80
:res +5
:res -5
:vertical resize +5
:vertical resize -5
```

and so on...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Code ( File on window ) >> Preferences >> Keyboard shortcuts.

to the top right there is an icon to open user keyboard shortcuts.

adjust the keys to your linkings.

```
  {
    "key": "ctrl+shift+o",
    "command": "workbench.action.decreaseViewSize"
  },
  {
    "key": "ctrl+shift+i",
    "command": "workbench.action.increaseViewSize"
  }
```

Comment: nice, I kind of prefer `ctrl+shift+i` and `ctrl+shift+d` for increase/decrease.

Comment: I used `ctrl+shift+alt+i` and `ctrl+shift+alt+d` because so many things were already taken by defaults and I don't like overriding defaults.

Answer (score 29):

There is no default shortcut for this but you can make your own.

Go to **File** > **Preferences** > **Keyboard shortcuts**

(or you can use the shortcut <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>k</kbd> <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>s</kbd> to open it on Linux and Windows, or <kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>k</kbd> <kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>s</kbd> on Mac)

Search for `current view size`  and you can set your custom key combinations for decreasing and increasing the size of the current view.

Comment: Is there a way to change the % of each fo those commands increase/decrease the size? It seems that every hit gives around 20 columns.

Comment: should mention also `Increase Editor Width` (and same with decrease) which changes only width and not width + height see https://stackoverflow.com/a/69485747/9544417

Answer (score 13):

1. On a Mac (If you are on Windows or Linux replace <kbd>cmd</kbd> with <kbd>ctrl</kbd>):

   <kbd>cmd</kbd>-<kbd>k</kbd> <kbd>cmd</kbd>-<kbd>s</kbd>
2. Type `current view size`
3. Double click on **Decrease Current View Size**

   Type whatever key combo you want. I like using <kbd>F3</kbd>
4. Double click on **Increase Current View Size**

   Type whatever key combo you want. I like using <kbd>F4</kbd>

Comment: "F4" is already used. I'd recommend "Ctrl+F7" and "Ctrl+F8"

Comment: whatever key combo you want

Answer (score 9):

In split view, if you double click the current editor tab then it will increase to max, double click again and it will reset to 50%. Not a shortcut key but pretty nice nonetheless

Comment: Ctrl+K and then ArrowKey can also be used to move editors without touching the mouse.

Answer (score 6):

The `Increase Current View Size` and `Decrease Current View Size` commands adjust both the width and the height of the view.

In case you would like too adjust just the width of the editor, use `Decrease editor width` and `Increase editor width` commands.