# Is it possible to make an editor split full-screen in VSCode?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'd like to have the ability to make one of multiple `split` editor windows full screen.

I usually have two vertically splitted windows with code and it would be useful to make sort of ***full-screen-zoom*** without explorer terminal and all other bars, just code.

Initally I have the following:

[image]

but I would like to configure a shortcut to make an active window full-screen like this:

[image]

It is like F11, closing the explorer, and merging the split. It is messy to do it by hand all the time...

Comment: [Take a peek at this similar question and answer:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43742604/vscode-shortcut-key-for-controlling-increasing-decreasing-current-split-panes/60174805#60174805)

Answer (score 41, accepted):

> I would like to configure a shortcut to make an active window full-screen.

You need to edit keybindings. Press `Ctrl+K` and then `Ctrl+S` to open keyboard shortcuts.

> If you're on a mac, use `Command` key instead of `Ctrl`.

Search **`full screen`** in search bar. You will see something like this:

[image: screenshot]

Click on the result. Press `Ctrl+K` and `Ctrl+K` (again!) or click pencil icon to edit the shortcut. Press desired key combination. That's it.

And here are some more shortcuts to learn:

Press `Ctrl+K` and then `Z` to open editor in full screen without explorer and terminal, etc. And you can use `Ctrl+B` to show/hide side bar and `Ctrl+J` to show terminal and console panel.

Download keyboard shortcuts file [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/keybindings#_keyboard-shortcuts-reference) for your favourite OS.

**To make these hotkeys work in vim-mode:**

Actually `VSCodeVim` will take over your control keys. This behaviour can be adjusted with the `useCtrlKeys` and handleKeys settings. Go to `File>>Preferences>>Keyboard Shortcuts`. Search for `Ctrl+k` in search bar. You will see `extension.vim_ctrl+k` as below:

[image: screenshotVim]

Change this hotkey. Now it should work.

Comment: Don't you know why don't these hotkeys work with vim-mode?

Comment: Very useful, thanks. So the vim extension just appeared to capture the <C-k> button (I use <C-w>k to navigate across splits actually so removing this capture does not affect me).

Comment: I wonder if `Ctrl+A` would work to select all in vim-mode! You may need to look over many shortcuts.

Comment: It seems `Ctrl+J`/`Ctrl+B` are also taken by vim extension. I don't remember a vim normal mode shortcut for them..

Comment: Btw, [this issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/54175) seems to not fixed yet. Very sad.

Comment: I had VScode version 1.15.1 and [this issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/54175) didn't occur. So, I updated VScode and yes this issue exists in VScode 1.27.2.

Comment: @St.Antario This wasn't the [issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/54175#issuecomment-433288828) with Zen mode. It's related with [Centered Layout](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/61673). BTW I'm on Windows 10.

Comment: on Window, You can press F11 to exit Full Screen

Answer (score 29):

The closest you can get to maximize ONE EDITOR GROUP out of two open editor groups,
(capitalizing because nobody read the actual question properly!)

is to set this command as a shortcut:

```
View: Toggle Editor Group Sizes
workbench.action.toggleEditorWidths
```

which will toggle the active editor group to 90% of the screen

If you have the side bar open that will take up another 10%,
to close that automatically use:

```
View: maximize Editor Group and Hide Sidebar
workbench.action.maximizeEditor
```

(this command doesn't toggle so you still need the previous shortcut)
(and also now your sidebar is closed when you toggle back)

To achieve maximum fullscreen vibe, use `Ctrl-k z` to enter zen mode, the sidebar, terminal, menus and clutter disappear,
leaving just the editor groups, which you can toggle their size with the previously mentioned shortcut.

Don't get lost in zen mode! It happens, remember the shortcut `Ctrl-k z`

Not ideal,
I think we'd all prefer to have dedicated toggles for zen-moding the active group editor or file 100%,
but it's close enough for now.

Here's a screenshot of it in action:

[image: https://i.postimg.cc/MT1j5xLR/zen-mode-and-editor-group-size-toggled.png]

Comment: Yup, this answer is the only one tackling the actual question of the OP.

Comment: Works for me, at least until there's official support for toggling between a usual view (multiple editor groups) and fullscreen of the current editor. This should be the accepted answer.

Comment: This is what I was looking for, thanks.

Comment: Hey What's that theme?

Comment: We can improve on this by adding keybindings

Comment: Double-clicking a tab seems to trigger `Toggle Editor Group Sizes` for me.

Answer (score 10):

VS Code Editor Full Screen Without Explorer and Terminal - Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd> then <kbd>Z</kbd> (Zen Mode)

To exit from the full screen mode, press <kbd>Esc</kbd> two times.

Comment: > To exit from the full screen mode, press Esc two times.

That doesn't work for me on windows, I have to use `Ctrl-k z`

Comment: `ctrl+k,z` doesn't make an editor full screen, when the OP is working with two side-by-side editors. It also doesn't make a single editor full-screen, just takes most of the screen (but not all).

Comment: works perfect with side-by-side editors too on Ubuntu 20.04.  Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

I use this on OSX, hope it will be helpful. Just replace command code with codef.

```
#!bin/sh
codef() {
  code $* && sleep 0.5 && /usr/bin/osascript -e \
    'tell application "Visual Studio Code"
      activate
      tell application "System Events"
          keystroke "f" using {control down, command down}
      end tell
    end tell'
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In windows to exit vscode full screen mode, press key

```
F11
```

To go back again into full screen mode, press key

```
F11
```

Answer (score 2):

the upate June 2021 from VS Code can move the [terminal inside the editor area](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_58#_integrated-terminal)

#### Step 1

The new `terminal.integrated.defaultLocation` setting can be set to `editor` to direct newly created terminals to the editor area by default.

#### Step 2

With the `Zen-Mode` ->  <kbd>Strg + K</kbd> + <kbd>Z</kbd> you get the full window terminal experience.

Comment: This is cool. As a vim/tmuxer I find this much more workable way to manage editors and terminals - they're all 1st class citizens. :-) Question, though, when i use this, and try to navigate to or from a terminal in the editor area using my vscode-neovim bindings (Ctrl+w h/j/k/l) the terminal goes "poof" and I have to create a new one.

Answer (score 1):

This solution is close to what was originally asked. I edited some vscode settings and now I can switch between 2 states quickly:

State 1: **have multiple (equal sized) editor splits open, maybe a terminal and the sidebar**

State 2: **have the current editor split bigger and the terminal and sidebar removed, at the same time vscode maximized to fullscreen**

To toggle I use `Ctrl+Alt+Z` and then `Ctrl+Alt+B`. To go back I type it in reverse order.

To make it work I inserted the following into my `~/.config/Code/User/keybindings.json`:

```
    {
        "key": "ctrl+alt+b",
        "command": "workbench.action.toggleEditorWidths"
    },
    {
        "key": "ctrl+alt+z",
        "command": "workbench.action.toggleZenMode"
    },
    {
        "key": "ctrl+k z",
        "command": "-workbench.action.toggleZenMode"
    },
```

It works for me in VSCode version 1.61 on Linux. On a Mac it would probably need some adjustments. On Windows it should be the same.

There is still a minor problem: After returning from zen mode, the cursor focus has moved to the terminal window, which is annoying and probably a VSCode bug. To solve it and return to where you were, using only the keyboard. if you have two splits, type:

`Ctrl+1` for the first split or `Ctrl+2` for the second

Answer (score 1):

We can improve on @bevo099's answer by adding keybindings.

This will cause F11 (the fullscreen key by default) to instead zoom-in on the active editor or terminal panel.  Zen mode is already full screen, so it replaces well.

I used the multi-command extension to allow multiple actions on one binding.

In `keybindings.json`:

```json
[
    {
        "key": "f11",
        "command": "extension.multiCommand.execute",
        "args": {
            "sequence": [
                "workbench.action.toggleEditorWidths",
                "workbench.action.toggleZenMode",
            ]
        },
        "when": "editorTextFocus && !inZenMode"
    },
    {
        "key": "f11",
        "command": "extension.multiCommand.execute",
        "args": {
            "sequence": [
                "workbench.action.toggleZenMode",
                "workbench.action.toggleEditorWidths",
            ]
        },
        "when": "editorTextFocus && inZenMode"
    },
    {
        "key": "f11",
        "command": "workbench.action.toggleMaximizedPanel",
        "when": "terminalFocus"
    }
]
```