# How can I make vs code on default ,everything vanished

Tags: visual-studio, settings

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EzYIC.png)
I have downloaded vs. code (new in programming), I have by-mistake clicked on some setting and after this everything vanished (example-closing tab, minimizing, maximizing)
would you mind helping me if you can

Answer (score 0):

You probably turned on fullscreen mode. Try turning it off using `F11`. More details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52680112/6645624).