# In Visual Studio, is there a way to quickly resize a splitted vertical document window?

Tags: visual-studio, ide, visual-studio-2022

This is similar to VS Code's [Increase/Decrease current view size](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43757116/653457). If possible, this is what I prefer: the view should increase its size whenever it has focus. For example, when `Program.cs` is being edited, it should be like this:

[image]

Then when I switch to `Program.AnotherFile.cs` (usually in MAUI or Blazor, with F7 hotkey), VS should automatically resize it like this:

[image]

Is this possible? I am open to installing extensions as well.

I have tried Window Layout (`Window` -> `Save Window Layout`), unfortunately it doesn't save/apply vertical split.